# How to convert an image into "data:image/svg+xml;base64"

Tags: css, xml, svg, base64

How can I convert an image into "data:image/svg+xml;base64"?

I have tried [**this**](https://www.base64-image.de/), but it only generates a `data:image/png;base64`. I would need `data:image/svg+xml;base64`. Do I need to save it in a specific way in (example) Photoshop?

Comment: You need to use some SVG Editor. Sadly, Photoshop cannot create true vector images. Take a look at answers here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data:image/png;base64` is for bitmap data (PNG) and
`data:image/svg+xml;base64` is for vector data (SVG).

So you'd need a program to convert bitmap data (pixels) to vector data which is quite complicated.

The other direction (vector to bitmap) is easy.

The difference explained in short:

- Vector data consists of complex objects (line, circle, ellipse, ...)
- Bitmap data consists of a sequence of points (point, point, point...)

Comment: Hey thanks. Is there any shortcut to convert bitmap into the vector data?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a Vector Graphics program like [SVG-Edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit).